# How to stop audio to play when user plays next audio?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple of music players in my website, all from a same plugin as

```
<audio id="player2" src="//filename" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
```

I want the previous audio player to stop when the user plays audio from another player.
I am a beginner so wish to have an easy explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen to the `play` event and run `pause` on other players.

```
var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio'); // We get a list of all audio elements
audios.forEach(function(player) { 
  player.addEventListener('play', function() { // We listen for the `play` event on each player
    audios.forEach(function(player2) {
      if (player !== player2) { // we find other players which don't match the one that started
        player2.pause(); // we pause those other players
      }
    });
  });
});
```